# Как сделать так что бы при выходе за белую область выводилось сообщение

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Я бы хотел узнать как сделать так что-бы при выходе за область  выводилось сообщение о том что вы пересекли ее.

```js
let dragMode = false;
            circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
                dragMode = true;
            });
            circle.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
                dragMode = false;
            });
    
    
    
    
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
                if (dragMode) {
                  circle.style.left = e.clientX - 50 + 'px';
                  circle.style.top = e.clientY - 50 + 'px';
                }
            });
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #333;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg>
        <rect fill="white" width="1440px" height="900px" onclick="click(event)"></rect>
    
    <div class="circle" id="circle">
          </svg>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я для выхода за пределы правой и нижней границ описал условия. Для остальных по аналогии. Про координаты элементов [вот тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates#koordinaty-otnositelno-okna-getboundingclientrect) неплохо рассказано. А вообще прикольный код. Я бы Drag`n`Drop кинулся применять. :)

```js
let dragMode = false;
let r = document.getElementById('f');
            circle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
                dragMode = true;
            });
            circle.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
                dragMode = false;
            });
    
    
    
    
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
                if (dragMode) {
                  circle.style.left = e.clientX - 50 + 'px';
                  circle.style.top = e.clientY - 50 + 'px';
                  
                  // вот тут условия
                  if(circle.getBoundingClientRect().x + 100 > r.getBoundingClientRect().x + r.getBoundingClientRect().width || circle.getBoundingClientRect().y + 100 > r.getBoundingClientRect().x + r.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
                    console.log('OUT!');
                  }
                }
            });
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #333;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg id="f">
        <rect fill="white" width="1440px" height="900px" onclick="click(event)"></rect>
    
    <div class="circle" id="circle">
          </svg>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ }:‑)